# R- how to access elements of a more 'complex' list, plus transform my complex list into a dataframe

Tags: r

I've got a little bit frustrated because I couldn’t figure out how to work properly with a more 'complex' list in R. Please, have a look.

I'm starting with this list here:

```
> test.results
  [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     
A 0.9375027 0.9995755 0.9997706 0.6900084 0.9207406
B 0.9375027 0.9375027 0.9997706 0.9375027 0.9207406
C 0.9375027 0.9375027 0.9997706 0.9375027 0.9954647
```

I would like to apply a function on each block (block#1 would be [,1]) of the list.

```
> as.matrix(test.results[,1])
  [,1]     
A 0.9375027
B 0.9375027
C 0.9375027
```

Let's say I want to compute the mean separately for each block [,1] to [,5] over A,B,C.
For block#1, this would be the same like computing the mean for the vector c(0.9375027, 0.9375027, 0.9375027), for block#2 the mean for vector c(0.9995755, 0.9995755, 0.9995755), ...

Optionally, I'm also interested in transforming the list into a dataframe:

```
1 A 0.9997706
1 B 0.9997706
1 C 0.9997706
2 A 0.9995755
2 B 0.9375027
2 C 0.9375027
. . . .
5 A  0.9207406 
5 B  0.9207406
5 C  0.9954647
```

1,2,..,5 indicate the original block number from the list here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `test.results` looks like a `matrix`, not like a `list`.

Comment: It is somehow both- a list and a matrix- at the same time (is.list() and is.matrix() both return TRUE). But I when I try the command  apply(test.results,2,sum) I get an ERROR in FUN(newX[, i], ...) because 'type' list is invalid here.

Comment: It would be better to post `dput(test.result)` then

Comment: dput(test.results)
structure(list(0.937502699053248, 0.999575503461592, 0.999999704128472, 0.690008379675631, 0.690008379675631, 0.405460605123654,...), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", 
"B", "C"), NULL))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
colMeans(test.results)
```

Then for changing your matrix you can use `melt` from `reshape2`

```
> m <- matrix(1:12, ncol=4)
> library(reshape2)
> melt(m)
   Var1 Var2 value
1     1    1     1
2     2    1     2
3     3    1     3
4     1    2     4
5     2    2     5
6     3    2     6
7     1    3     7
8     2    3     8
9     3    3     9
10    1    4    10
11    2    4    11
12    3    4    12
```

(In your case `Var1` and `Var2` would be 1,2,..,5 and A,B, and C)

EDIT:

```
test.result <- as.matrix(read.delim(text="0.9375027 0.9995755 0.9997706 0.6900084 0.9207406
0.9375027 0.9375027 0.9997706 0.9375027 0.9207406
0.9375027 0.9375027 0.9997706 0.9375027 0.9954647", header=F, sep=" "))

rownames(test.result) <- LETTERS[1:3]
colnames(test.result) <- NULL

> test.result
       [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
A 0.9375027 0.9995755 0.9997706 0.6900084 0.9207406
B 0.9375027 0.9375027 0.9997706 0.9375027 0.9207406
C 0.9375027 0.9375027 0.9997706 0.9375027 0.9954647

> class(test.result)
[1] "matrix"

> colMeans(test.result)
[1] 0.9375027 0.9581936 0.9997706 0.8550046 0.9456486
```

EDIT 2:

You have a list "structured" as a matrix... like this probably:

```
test <- structure(list(1, 11, 111, 2, 22, 222), .Dim = c(3L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
  NULL, c("a", "b")))

> test
     a   b  
[1,] 1   2  
[2,] 11  22 
[3,] 111 222

> is.list(test)
[1] TRUE
> is.matrix(test)
[1] TRUE
> colMeans(test)
Error in colMeans(test) : 'x' must be numeric
```

If so, you just need to unlist and then give the object the previous structure:

```
> (test <- matrix(unlist(test), nrow(test)))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]   11   22
[3,]  111  222
> is.list(test)
[1] FALSE
> colMeans(test)
[1] 41 82
```

Comment: Second part works here. colMeans(test.results) gives an Error in my case: 'x' has to be numeric. However, I can do my operations on the dataframe as well.

Comment: @myX. Hi, are you saying that `colMeans(test.result)` gave the above error? Please check my edit.

Comment: @myX. Just read your comment above saying about is.list and is.matrix. Find the 2nd edit please

Answer (score 1):

For your the columns mean compute , `colMeans` is the best answer.

To put your matrix in the long format ( the second part of your question) you can use `stack`:

```
    dd <- stack(test.results)
    dd$ind <- rownames(test.results)

      values ind
1  0.9375027   A
2  0.9375027   B
3  0.9375027   C
4  0.9995755   A
5  0.9375027   B
6  0.9375027   C
7  0.9997706   A
8  0.9997706   B
9  0.9997706   C
10 0.6900084   A
11 0.9375027   B
12 0.9375027   C
13 0.9207406   A
14 0.9207406   B
15 0.9954647   C
```